# How to avoid repeating virtualhost properties in apache?

Tags: apache

I want my sites served via SSL to have a bunch of the same properies in my apache2 config. Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere that demos how to do that. Here's my config at the moment for two separate servers accessed by `www.mydomain.com` and `blog.mydomain.com`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

    # Repeated stuff
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

  </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ServerName blog.mydomain.com

    # Repeated stuff
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

As you can see, both virtualhosts have a lot of the same properties under `#Repeated stuff`. How can I specify these properties once and then have ONLY these virtualhosts inherit those properties? E.g. can virtualhosts be nested?

Comment: You may want to look at the [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_macro` gave me just what I wanted. On ubuntu it can simply be enabled with `sudo a2enmod macro`. My apache2 SSL config now looks something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<Macro SSLStuff>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
</Macro>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Use SSLStuff
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Use SSLStuff
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ServerName blog.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Use SSLStuff
    ServerName mynodeapp.mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```